# How to calculate nonlinear simultaneous equation where the 1st derivative =0?

Tags: nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

The equations should be solved

$ h(x,y)=x+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}-\text{inp}_x$,
$~$$ g(x,y)=y+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}-\text{inp}_y
$, where $\text{inp}_x$ and $\text{inp}_y$ are constant.

I tried to solve the equations by Newton-Raphson (NR) methods for root finding.

But, I couldn't solve the equations where $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$ and/or $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$.

For a $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\neq0$ system, am I right to calculate

- $h(x,y)$ as optimization problem (i.e., finding extrema point),
- substituted optimized y_value into $g(x,y)$, and 3rdly solve $g(x,y)$ by NR mothods?

If I am not, please tell me how to solve the equations.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please see [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting Maths nicely on this site. Please use it to rewrite your question so it is easier to read

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My considering algorithm above doesn't work well (Maybe hessian matrix in my code is wrong). For now, I' ll check the matrix.